# Can we use pointer of enum variable in C

Tags: c

```
enum States { state1 , state2 };

States var = state2;
```

Can I use address of enum variable in C? For example `fun(&var);`

Comment: Yes you can use address of a enum variable..

Comment: What makes you think that you cannot?

Comment: What is the problem that you are having? Taking address is fine, but if you are having something like compilation error, then include relevant information in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Once you create a variable, you have an object on your hands. You can take the address of that object just fine.

What you may not do however, is to take the address of an enumerator. I.e. nothing like `fun(&state1);` or `fun(&state2);`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, enums are objects that you can take the address of.

The only objects in C without an address are bit-fields and objects declared with the `register` storage-class specifier.